# PhoneGap installation issues

Tags: android, batch-file, cordova, ant

I am trying to setup PhoneGap on a new Windows 7 machine. Downloads and installs all go fine. In a command prompt I type java, adb, android and they respond correctly, but when I run the ant command it gives me

**1. ant is not recognized as an internal command, operable program or batch.file**

also

1. when I follow the PhoneGap documnentation path syntax for Windows:-

**C:\path\to\cordova-android\bin\create.bat C:\path\to\my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName**

I receive the following following prompt:-

The filename, directory name or volume label name syntax is incorrect.

I am not to sure where to go from here as I have also appended JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME to my environment variables when I run create.bat with the variables.

I am using PhoneGap 2.9.0 (have previously used PhoneGap 2.9.1), eclipse/ADT and Win 7.

Comment: Did you actually create the `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` environment variables?  Based on the error It would seem like your ANT_HOME isn't set up correctly.

Comment: I appended the JAVA_HOME and the full ANT_HOME path (ie.C:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.zip\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin) to the environment variables PATH, but I still get an error message

Comment: ANT_HOME isn't supposed to include the "\bin"